# How to get hashed value from URL

Tags: jquery, hash

How do I get hashed value from url into separate variables `url#value1=abc&value2=xyz&value3=123` like this

```
var value1 = 'abc';
var value2 = 'xyz';
var value3 = 123;
```

if any variable not present in url then,

```
var value4 = 0;
```

I used `window.location.hash` to get all hashed value, but how would I separate this into separate variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found JavaScript doesn't have concept of associative array, although we can do it by creating an object.
Through this code we can get the values into the object in the form of key and value.

```
var href = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var hash = href.split("&");
var scroll = new Object();
for(key in hash){
    var arr = hash[key].split("=");
    scroll[arr[0]] = arr[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a better choice to use an array and not separate variables.

```
var hashValues = window.location.hash.substr(1).split("&");
```

And id you want them in variables, might be better as an object instead of flooding the global scope.

```
var vals = { "value1" : 0 };
for(var i=hashValues.length;i++) {
    vals["value"+i] = hashValues[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Get value with hashtag (#):**

```
var hash = location.hash;
```

**Get value after hashtag (#):**

```
var hash = location.hash.substr(1);
```

**Get hash value from href:**

```
this.hash; //  returns the hash value from href attributes of an anchor tag.
```

For example:

```
<a href="http://www.codexworld.com/index.php#VideoTutorial" onclick="alert(this.hash)">Get Hash</a>
```

Source: [CodexWorld](https://www.codexworld.com/how-to/get-hash-value-from-url-using-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.split()`:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var split = hash.split('&');
var value1 = split[0];
var value2 = split[1];
var value3 = split[2];
if(value1 == "" || value2 == "" || value3 == "") {
    var value = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem with 3 parameters.

```
var hash = this.hash.substr(1);

if(hash == ""){
    var value4 = 0;
}

var value1Raw = hash.split('&')[0];
var value2Raw = hash.split('&')[1];
var value3Raw = hash.split('&')[2];

var value1 = value1Raw.substring(7);
var value2 = value2Raw.substring(7);
var value3 = value3Raw.substring(7);
```

Comment: Sorry, I have forgot to mention the value in URL. I have updated my question please review it again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can we convert the string like 
`apiscroll=4&altscroll=3&category=somecategory`  
  

into associative array with key value pair like  
`hash[apiscroll] = 4; hash[altscroll] = 3; hash[category] = somecategory`